# Find all the limit points of $\{n/\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}/n: n\in \mathbb N\}$

Tags: real-analysis

My try.
Negative number cannot be the limit point as if take any negative number as a limit point then its nhd will not contain infinite element of set.but what about zero and positive number???
Please help

Comment: What must happen for it to get close to a positive number like 2?

Comment: 2 may be a limit point..but i am not sure

Comment: What happens to $n/\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2/n$ as $n$ gets large?

Comment: I am not getting any proper answer .. please help

Answer (score 4):

Define $x_n=n/\sqrt2+\sqrt2/n.$

Note that for $n \ge 2,$ $$x_n-x_{n-1}=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} - \frac {\sqrt2} {n(n-1)},$$ so $x_2=x_1$ but for $n>2,$ $$x_n-x_{n-1}\ge\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} - \frac {\sqrt2} 6.$$  Thus the points in $\{x_n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ are isolated points, and so that set has no limit points.